# Ubuntu causes Windows USB to not work

Tags: usb, windows

Sorry, I an VERY new to Ubuntu

I have a Windows 10 machine and a Ubuntu 20 machine.

My Windows machine frequently can NOT read a USB that Ubuntu has put a files on.

When I use the USB on Ubuntu and then reinsert it into Windows it does NOT see the USB.

Windows makes the normal  little beep sound when I insert the USB, but windows explorer does NOT show it in the list of drives.

If I go Windows Disk Management it shows the USB and says “Healthy (Active Primary Partition)”, but Windows Explorer does NOT show the USB disk.

For awhile I can occasionally use the USB normally on both machines, but if I use it much on Ubuntu, then the USB will become unusable on Windows.

However if I put it back in Ubuntu, the USB works fine.

***What am I doing wrong??????***

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: "However if I put it back in Ubuntu, the USB works fine."  Then this is a Windows problem or a hardware problem (like an unsafe remove of the USB). Not Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS are different Ubuntu products, so please be precise (*correct your question rather than add contradictory detail as 20 != 20.04*).  Did you properly eject the thumb-drive; as otherwise the buffers may not have been cleared & thumb-drive data was incomplete; data not on drive will be ignored by other machines it's used in regardless of OS - only writing OS will see the data (*as it still has missing data in uncleared buffers*)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that Windows can have problems with file systems created by Ubuntu, even when it is a Microsoft file system. What file system is it?

Maybe you can repair the file system.

- Try to use a method, that does not destroy files (a non-destructive method).
- If that fails, use Ubuntu to copy the files to another drive and after that let Windows format the USB drive to FAT32 or exFAT or NTFS.

NTFS is the most reliable file system among these because it has journaling. Unfortunately Windows refuses to read Linux file systems.